# How to get all results that fall under each weeks based on given date for the past 6 months using laravel and carbon

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

I have many records created each day and I would like to know how many records are completed for each week based on the date created. The query perhaps would be something like this

```
$records_weekly = DB::table('records')

   ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subMonths(4))

   ->groupBy('week')

   ->get()

   ->toArray();
```

Comment: post your migrations too

Comment: you can consider having a table with posts. What I need is to know is number of posts posted for each week based on the date created. For example: on week one: 10, week two: 8, week three: 40 and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope u are having eloquent:

```
$date = Carbon::now();

$records_weekly = Records::all()->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subMonths(4))
                            ->groupBy(function($date) {
                                return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('W');
                            })->sortKeysDesc();
```

This will product output like, note `20`, `21`, `22` are week numbers

```
{
    "20": [...],
    "21": [...],
    "22": [
           {
            "id": 19,
            .....
            "created_at": "2018-05-31 07:46:33",
            "updated_at": "2018-05-23 07:46:33"
           }
          ]
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but i got this the error: Method sortKeysDesc does not exist. Basically what i would need is to show record similar to your output. For example: week one: 20, week two: 10, week three: 8 etc.

Comment: u may just remove that `sortKeysDesc`. and check it